# Aws Athena table schema for mixed structure logs json and space separated

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create aws Athena table schema for mixed structure logs. that's logs contain space separated values then JSON data (key value). Is it possible? if possible can you please suggest me which serde should I use and what would be input.regex. sample data as below

`<14>1 2017-08-16T07:31:51.987129Z ip-10-xxx-xx-xx something-abc-abc-abc-access-nginx - - - { "time": "16/Aug/2017:07:31:51 +0000", "remote_addr": "xx.xx.xx.xxx", "remote_user": "-", "http_x_forwarded_for": "11.332.125.57", "body_bytes_sent": 478, "request_time": "0.023", "status": 200, "request": "GET /v1/abcd/ac4e427d223a369edf HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "-", "http_header": "bltdfeb4fe089b00feb", "http_header_old": "-", "http_user_agent": "-" }`

Comment: try regEx serde. Also mention what are the columns you want in your table out of this sample record.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch JSON data values in the table like time,remote_addr,remote_user so on. have tried up with serde2.RegexSerDe not able to get proper regex.

Comment: As asked before. Please put sample record and put the query you used to create table using regex serde in question itself. It would help a lot

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, Have created Regex :- '(?:[^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([([^ ]*)^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) (?:[{ ]) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]* +[^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?:[ } ])